# How to make HTML canvas objects move with a cursor and slow down over time?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am new to JavaScript and currently working on small 2d game, where in a html canvas element, I have drawn a puck and a small goal line, and the point of the "game" is to throw the puck to the goal. My problem currently is that I just do not know how to make the puck move with my mouse controls. I've tried to use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) as reference to a lot of the code, but it seems like I'm struggling to impltement other stuff in to my own code.

Here's a part of my code as well.
The part that currently takes control of the puck

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownHandler, false);
// When user clicks, the puck starts following the cursor
function mouseDownHandler(e) {

dx = 0;
dy = 0;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUpHandler, false);
function mousemoveHandler(e) {
var relativeX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
var relativeY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
if (relativeX > 0 && relativeX < canvas.width) {
  x = relativeX - 18 / 2;
} if (relativeY > 0 && relativeY < canvas.height) {
  y = relativeY - 20 / 2;
}
}
function mouseUpHandler(e) {
  dx = -dx + 1;
  dy = -dy - 1;
  x += 0;
  y += 0;
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemoveHandler, false);
 }
}
```

And then my variables:

```
// Variables used
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameArea");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// Coordinates used for the puck
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height/2;
// Coordinates used to make the puck "move" as a placeholder"
var dx = 0;
var dy = 0;

// Gives the puck a radius that is used for calculations
var puckRadius = 10;
var goalieRadius = 57;

// Variables for goalie
var z = canvas.width/2;
var a = 5;

//variable for counting score
var score = 0;

// Variables for goal size and location
var goalHeight = 10;
var goalWidth = 115;
var goalX = (canvas.width-goalWidth)/2;
```

Tell me if you need anything more and thank you in advance!

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/6gn48dbq/1/ Also a Jfiddle of the work!

Comment: A full example will be nice...

Comment: ...think about the real world, all moving objects have a `speed` and they slowdown because of `friction` ... that right there are two variable that you have to consider for your puck

Comment: @HelderSepu That's true, but my problem lies more on how to implement the speed variable in to the puck, and how to get it to keep moving even after letting go of it

Comment: I see your Jfiddle...  so your speed is on    ` dx = -dx + 1;` (same for y) change that 1 to a 5 and you can see that puck flying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So following up on my comment...

You need to add the speed in your mouse:

```
function mouseUpHandler(e) {
  dx = -dx + speed;
  dy = -dy - speed;
```

...and later that speed could be controlled by a slider `<input type="range">` fun fun

And on every pass of the draw you apply the friction:

```
function draw() {
  dx *= friction;
  dy *= friction;
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nfdyLv61/

Comment: That looks super good! Is there any way to make the direction of the puck so that the player can choose it? Thank you either way!

Comment: Sure, that speed is actually a vector, instead of one speed change that to speedX and speedY and play with different values (positive and negatives) you should see the puck changing direction.